# Can I debug (step through) code without a main() function?

Tags: c++, debugging, code-analysis

Assume I want to understand a larger project by just stepping through the code with a debugger. Is it possible to just jump in at an arbitrary point (given I define the correct variables)? How do I debug libraries that don't have a main?

Comment: Libraries don't have a main. That's why your test code has one and you start debugging from there.

Comment: It is possible but only if you are a debugging guru and can construct the calling stack frame by hand using the debugger commands.

Comment: @RichardCritten How would I even do that?

Comment: Perhaps learn about unit testing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To debug code in a library, write a little application (that has a `main()`) that calls the functions in the library you need to debug. Then debug that application and step into the library calls it makes.

As for just "jumping into an arbitrary location" - well, you *can* instruct the debugger to move the instruction pointer to wherever you please, but that's usually not what you want, because you'd be missing a lot of state that previous parts of the program will have created. Usually what you *want* to do is set a breakpoint in the function you are interested in and then just run the program normally until you hit the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to run the application as it is and set a breakpoint whenever you want to look. The thing is that the program might do lot of initialization and other stuff, that you wouldn't be able to figure out.
Another approach would be to look out for unit tests. They are like small programs itself targeting just specific parts of the program.